# ¿Por que el onClick de un enlace hace referencia a otro enlace?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un ul y dentro de ese ul 3 li que tienen dentro enlaces. Para esos enlaces cada uno tiene una funcionalidad, y el ultimo necesito que cierre sesión (que lo hace) y lleve al index (Que también lo hace). El primero de los li tengo que hacer que vaya a otra página y solo eso, pero cuando le doy me cierra la sesión. Si quito el php del tercer li sigue con la sesión, asi que el php es el problema, alguno sabe que pasa?
Gracias y un saludo

```
<article class="top-nav">
        <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class='menu-button-container' for="menu-toggle">
            <div class='menu-button' onclick="visualizarMenu();"></div>
        </label>introducir el código aquí
        <ul class="menu" id="menu_desplegable">
            <li id="anunciate"><a href="SubirAnuncio.php">ANUNCIATE</a></li>
            <li id="loginHead"><a href="Login.php">LOG IN</a></li>
            <li id="cerrarSesionHeader"><a href="index.php" onclick="<?php destroySession(); ?>">CERRAR SESIÓN</a></li>
        </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: No podemos saber qué pasa sin ver el PHP. Pero antes de eso, quizá deberíamos ver cómo manejas el asunto en Javascript, ahí también podrían ocurrir cosas que estén dislocando todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que no pruebas seguir el metodo que hiciste antes con SubirAnuncio.php y Login.php e implementar el logout.php. Te dejo una idea, espero que te sirva! :) Un saludo!

```
<article class="top-nav">
            <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox"/>
            <label class='menu-button-container' for="menu-toggle">
                <div class='menu-button' onclick="visualizarMenu();"></div>
            </label>introducir el código aquí
            <ul class="menu" id="menu_desplegable">
                <li id="anunciate"><a href="SubirAnuncio.php">ANUNCIATE</a></li>
                <li id="loginHead"><a href="Login.php">LOG IN</a></li>
                <li id="cerrarSesionHeader"><a href="logout.php">CERRAR SESIÓN</a></li>
            </ul>
    </article>


    //authenticate/logout.php

    <?php   
    session_start(); //Para asegurarte de que la sesion esta iniciada
    session_destroy(); //Destruir la sesion
    echo 'You have been logged out. <a href="authenticate/index.php">Go back</a>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Gracias! Si que es por eso